# How to properly move canvas object with more than 2 values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create canvas HTML 5 to move object and stop when it reaches end. For this, I have 10 values for X and 10 for Y. Firstly, I need to put all the values as coordinates of X and Y. On clicking the button, Animation should be started and stopped when reaches end.

Note: I have to work it out with 10 values for each X and Y also Fish move must be stopped when reaches last value of X and Y. This is the requirement that I have to follow.

My code is only working for the first two X and Y values. I dont know how to do the rest. I have tried to create the `for loop` inside `GetStarted()` function but it didnt work as well.

```js
function GetStarted(){

  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  // get the canvas's 2d context
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // clear the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // get the position
  var abc = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
  var xyz = Number(document.getElementById("y").value); 

  // creating an image from scratch
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a8/fish.png";

  // when the image are loaded,   
  // draw the image at the specified position
  image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image, abc, xyz); 
  };
}
}
```

```css
#x,#y {
width : 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td> X </td> 
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
<td> <input id="x" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Y </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td>
<td> <input id="y" /> </td> 
</tr>
</table>
<button onClick="GetStarted()">
Swim little fish</button>
<br /><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="300"
style="border:1px solid black;">
Your browser does not support canvas.
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a8/fish.png" id="fishes">

</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have i misunderstood anything?

Comment: why you need all 10 values for X & Y.
You can have start value and end value for X & Y and do animation on that basic by making step value 10.

Comment: Because this is the requirement that I have to enter upto 10 values for X and Y and then click the button. The animation will then start with initial values and stop when Fish reaches at the last values.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear at all and while there are some obvious flaws in your current code, it will be hard to help you correctly. Do all the objects share the same "end"? Do they need to go from their position to the last one by passing through all the middle positions? (i.e first would go through all 10 and last would stay static)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point to move your fish:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = y = 0

// creating an image from scratch
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, x, y);
};
image.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a8/fish.png";

function GetStarted() {
  setInterval(Move, 20)
}

function Move() {
  x = (x + 9) % canvas.width;
  y = (y + 1) % canvas.height; 
  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="GetStarted()">Swim little fish</button> <br /><br />

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="170" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

As you can see I have significantly changed your code!

Now the fish moves, but there are no place to enter the X & Y like you had what you had was not going to make a very smooth movement instead it will be more like jumping around, also you can not give the same id to html elements and expect you can get the one you need using `document.getElementById("y")` that just was not going to work

Comment: Yes it is working, But I have to work it out with upto 10 values for each X and Y. Also Fish move must be stopped when reaches last value of X and Y. This is the requirement that I have to follow.

Comment: Use that and restrict it to 10 values

Comment: @mmkk347 Correct, this code is meant as a starting point, it is up to you to make it work in your system